# Where clause with math

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I have a column in the table named Contacted which holds the date of contact formatted like Y-m-d. 
I want my cronjob file to take only those entries where Contacted value was 7 days ago. So I do this

```
$checkstat = "Contacted";
$checkdate = date("Y-m-d");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE Status = '$checkstat' AND Contacted - '$checkdate' = 7");
```

But it doesn't work. Idea is to substract the dates and result should be 7 if 7 days passed, but it doesn't fetch anything. What could be the problem?

Comment: You're probably going to have to use the mySQL DATEDIFF function.

Comment: What datatype is Contacted in your table?

Comment: Contacted is date datatype, formatted Y-m-d same as checkdate. So I can't just substract?

Comment: Just tried running this:
`$checkstat = "Contacted";
$checkdate = date("Y-m-d");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE Status = '$checkstat' AND DATEDIFF(Contacted,'$checkdate') = 7");`

Doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of subtracting in MySQL and repeating that operation for every row, why not just send the "seven days from now" date?

Something like this:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d');
$seven_days_from_today = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+7 days", strtotime($date)));

// Your query
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE Status = '$checkstat' AND Contacted = '$seven_days_from_today'");
```

Side note: `mysql_` functions are deprecated.  Please start looking into using either [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [pdo](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: I'll have to modify it a bit. 3 cron jobs, 2nd runs 7 days after first, 3rd 7 days after 2nd. So 1st cron job would have to add seven_days_from_now and second cron would check if today is seven days from now. Let me try to code this and get back with a solution, thank you. By the way, my first site ever, so I didn't know that mysql_ functions are deprecated =)

Comment: It worked! I added another column "todo" so crons know which one should run (they scan the db every day so they won't overlap)
Cron number 1: set 7 days column to 7 days from the moment of running, set todo for Cron 2
Cron number 2: check if 7 days from now is today, check if todo is set for cron 2, if yes execute, set 7 days from now and set todo for cron 3
Cron number 3: check if 7 days from now is today, check if todo is set for cron 3, if yes execute.

Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome.  Now that this is cron, it's very easy to forget the use of `mysql_`.  I've added links to mysqli and pdo in my answer.

Comment: Thanks again! I'll make sure I do the switch right after this project (would be too long to change everything now).

Answer (score 0):

You can define your "Contacted" column as int and then use PHP functions like strtodate() and datetostr() ,... to convert that integer into any format you want and do arithmetic operations on it.
for example you can user PHP date("u") function, this will return time as an integer so you can easily save it into DB and manipulate it.